# TiKz package: How to replace dots with numbers in function domain range map

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I trying to figure out how to replace the dots in the circles with numerical values (1, 2, 3, etc)

Please help me identify what code lines I need to edit to accomplish this replacement.

Thanks in advance!

mwe (h/t pecusse)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%put some nodes on the left
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (d\x) at (0,\x) {};
}
\node[fit=(d1) (d2) (d3),ellipse,draw,minimum width=1cm] {}; 
%put some nodes on the center
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.5,1.5,...,4}{
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (r\xi) at (2,\x) {};
}
\node[fit=(r1) (r2) (r3) (r4),ellipse,draw,minimum width=1.5cm] {}; 
%put some nodes on the right
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.75,1.5,...,3}{
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (c\xi) at (4,\x) {};
}
\node[fit=(c1) (c2) (c3) (c4) ,ellipse,draw,minimum width=1.5cm] {};
\draw[-latex] (d1) -- (r2);
\draw[-latex] (d2) -- (r2);
\draw[-latex] (d3) -- (r4);
\draw[-latex] (r1) -- (c2);
\draw[-latex] (r2) -- (c3);
\draw[-latex] (d3) -- (r4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The empty braces at end of `node` commands produces an empty node. Insert some contents there.

Comment: @Sigur , I tried this:

Comment: @Sigur , I tried this: `\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (d\x) at (0,\x) {};
}`      ..replaced `file, circle` with `1,2,3`. Filled circles disappeared but the number don't show. Clearly I'm not understanding your helpful instructions.

Comment: The node contents should be placed between the *curly* braces: `\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (d\x) at (0,\x) {`<here>`};`. In this case, you probably want: `\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (d\x) at (0,\x) {\x};` since `\x` holds the numbers `1`, `2` and `3` when going through the `\foreach` loop. Of course, you need to change the fill color to something else than black ... maybe try `fill=lightgray` ...

Comment: @SiuslawMath, see Jasper's comments. The `fill` is a key to fill the node. The `circle` key means that the node is circle shaped. The node contents should be insert in the last braces pair. For example, `\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (r\xi) at (2,\x) {\xi};` since the counter is stored in `\xi` variable.

Comment: @Sigur @JasperHabicht
Forgive me for being extremely dense in being able to execute your code suggestions. `\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (r\xi) at (2,\x) {\xi};` produced fatal error. Also, I need to replace the black dots in the node oval with just the numbers. Should have posted this image [sorry, my school blocks imgur] https://www.dropbox.com/s/cng47k4dwy204pu/Domain_range%20x%20y%20mapping%20diagram.png?dl=0

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an alternative solution without any background behind the numbers, since the picture you posted in your last comment does not have any background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which numbers you would like to place where, but in general, the contents of a node should be placed between the curly braces: `\node[options] (name) at (0,0) {` ... `};`.

In your example, you might want to place into the nodes the numbers from the `\foreach` loop that are stored in the macro `\x`. Since the nodes are filled black, the text inside would not be visible. Therefore, I would suggest that you change the fill color using, for example, `fill=lightgray`. So, you can write something like: `\node[fill=lightgray,circle,inner sep=2pt] (d\x) at (0,\x) {\x};`.

If you do this for all three sets of nodes, you will discover that the node contents are of different length and therefore, the circles will have a different size. For example, some nodes only contain one digit, while others contain three and a dot as decimal separator. You probably want to add the option `minimum width=2.5em` (or similar) to the nodes in order to get the same size for all nodes.

Finally, because the nodes might overlap due to the increased size, you can set the option `y=1.25cm` for the entire `tikzpicture` which increasing the vertical distances while keeping the horizontal distances as they where.

Taken everything together, you would get:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1.25cm]
%put some nodes on the left
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \node[fill=lightgray,circle,inner sep=2pt,minimum width=2.5em] (d\x) at (0,\x) {\x};
}
\node[fit=(d1) (d2) (d3),ellipse,draw,minimum width=1cm] {}; 

%put some nodes on the center
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.5,1.5,...,3.5}{
    \node[fill=lightgray,circle,inner sep=2pt,minimum width=2.5em] (r\xi) at (2,\x) {\x};
}
\node[fit=(r1) (r2) (r3) (r4),ellipse,draw,minimum width=1.5cm] {}; 

%put some nodes on the right
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.75,1.5,...,3}{
    \node[fill=lightgray,circle,inner sep=2pt,minimum width=2.5em] (c\xi) at (4,\x) {\x};
}
\node[fit=(c1) (c2) (c3) (c4),ellipse,draw,minimum width=1.5cm] {};

\draw[-latex] (d1) -- (r2);
\draw[-latex] (d2) -- (r2);
\draw[-latex] (d3) -- (r4);
\draw[-latex] (r1) -- (c2);
\draw[-latex] (r2) -- (c3);
\draw[-latex] (d3) -- (r4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you don't want any background behind the numbers, you can probably delete the options to the nodes altogether (also, you would not need to set `y=1.25cm`). You might want to add some color (similar to the picture you provided in your comment), hence I added some color to the left oval and one of the arrows:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%put some nodes on the left
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \node (d\x) at (0,\x) {\x};
}
\node[fit=(d1) (d2) (d3),ellipse,draw=blue,minimum width=1cm] {}; 

%put some nodes on the center
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.5,1.5,...,3.5}{
    \node (r\xi) at (2,\x) {\x};
}
\node[fit=(r1) (r2) (r3) (r4),ellipse,draw,minimum width=1.5cm] {}; 

%put some nodes on the right
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.75,1.5,...,3}{
    \node (c\xi) at (4,\x) {\x};
}
\node[fit=(c1) (c2) (c3) (c4),ellipse,draw,minimum width=1.5cm] {};

\draw[-latex,orange] (d1) -- (r2);
\draw[-latex] (d2) -- (r2);
\draw[-latex] (d3) -- (r4);
\draw[-latex] (r1) -- (c2);
\draw[-latex] (r2) -- (c3);
\draw[-latex] (d3) -- (r4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]